# How to instruct Excel to go copy a range of cells from left to right?

Tags: excel, reorderlist

So basically, my sheet has a list of items, but they are ordered like this:

```
A2 | Item 1 Code | Item 1 name | Quantity | Item 2 code | Item 2 name | Quantity
A3 | Item 3 Code | Item 3 name | Quantity | Item 4 code | Item 4 name | Quantity
```

etc.

I want to reorder the items to make it a single list, since the codes should remain in the same order after filtering and it's been quite a conundrum. I tried putting like

```
=B2 | =C2 | =D2
=E2 | =F2 | =G2
=B3 | =C3 | =D3
=E3 | =F3 | =G3
```

and then auto-filling, but as you may imagine, that caused Excel to start skipping rows as it got to the end of the formulas it was copying to the lower cells.

Anyone able to explain to me how to fix this? :')

Comment: You can write a function that takes the items as arguments. Learn more about writing a function in excel: https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest but it may work for you:

[image]

Formula in column I is:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW());INDEX($B$1:$B$9;ROUNDUP(ROW()/2;0));INDEX($E$1:$E$9;ROUNDUP(ROW()/2;0)))
```

Formula in column J:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW());INDEX($C$1:$C$9;ROUNDUP(ROW()/2;0));INDEX($F$1:$F$9;ROUNDUP(ROW()/2;0)))
```

Formula in column K:

```
=IF(ISODD(ROW());INDEX($D$1:$D$9;ROUNDUP(ROW()/2;0));INDEX($G$1:$G$9;ROUNDUP(ROW()/2;0)))
```

It's always same formula, but changing target range. After dragging, copy/paste values and delete original data:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This did exactly what I needed :)